# A proof of a theorem on the different in algebraic number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

**Theorem**
Let $K ⊂ L ⊂ E$ be a tower of algebraic number fields.
Suppose that $E/K$ is a Galois extension.
Let $B$ and $C$ be the rings of algebraic integers in $L$ and $E$ respectively.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $E/K$.
Let $H$ be the Galois group of $E/L$.
Let $G/H$ be the set of left cosets of $G$ by $H$.
Let $S$ be the set of representatives of $G/H - \{H\}$. 
For each $\sigma ∈ S$, Let $J_\sigma$ be the ideal of $C$ generated by the set $\{x - \sigma(x); x ∈ B\}$.
Let $J$ be $\prod_{\sigma ∈ S}J_\sigma$.
Let $D_{L/K}$ be the [different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal).
Then $(D_{L/K})C = J$.

I know a proof of this theorem which uses a somewhat complicated argument using the Kronecker's method on forms. I'm looking for a simpler proof without forms.
Perhaps one can prove this by using p-adic completions, but I prefer a proof using only ideals.

**EDIT**
As a corollary to this theorem, we get the following useful result.

**Corollary**
Let $L$ be a finite Galois extension of an algebraic number field K.
Let $B$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $L$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $L/K$.
For each $\sigma ∈ G - \{1\}$, Let $J_\sigma$ be the ideal of $B$ genertated by the set $\{x - \sigma(x); x ∈ B\}$.
Let $D_{L/K}$ be the different.
Then $D_{L/K} = \prod_{\sigma ∈ G - \{1\}}J_\sigma$.

**EDIT**
By the way, I guess the word the different came from the above theorem.

**EDIT**
For the readers convenience, I will prove the theorem using the Kronecker's method.
The proof is largely borrowed from the Takagi's book "Algebraic number theory"(in Japanese).
I have simplified it using localizations. After all, it's not so complicated as I thought.
For a technical reason, we prove the theorem under the following more general conditions.
Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions.
Let $L$ be a finite separable extension of $K$.
Let $E$ be a finite Galois extension of $K$ such that $L ⊂ E$.
Let $B$ and $C$ be the integral closures of $A$ in $L$ and $E$ respectively.

Let $B[X_1, ..., X_m]$ be the polynomial ring over B.
Let $F ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_m]$.
We denote by $I(F)$ the ideal of $B$ generated by all the coefficients of $F$.
Given $F, G ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_m]$, it can be proved by a simple argument which goes back to Gauss that $I(FG)$ = $I(F)I(G)$(for example, see theorem 13 in Hilbert's "The theory of algebraic number fields").
This fact is the basis of the Kronecker's theory of forms.

Since $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, there exist elements $\theta_1､...､\theta_m$ which generate $B$ as an $A$-module.
Let $\eta$ = $\theta_1X_1 + ... + \theta_mX_m ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_m]$.
Let $T = S ∪$ {1}.
Let $G(Y)$ = $\prod_{\sigma ∈ T}(Y - \sigma(\eta)) ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_m][Y]$.
Let $G'(Y)$ be the formal derivative of $G(Y)$ with respect to $Y$.
Then $G'(\eta)$ = $\prod_{\sigma ∈ S}(\eta - \sigma(\eta)) ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_m]$.
Let $I$ = $I(G'(\eta))$.
Since $J_\sigma = CI(\eta - \sigma(\eta))$ for $\sigma ∈ S$, $J$ = $C(\prod_{\sigma ∈ S}I(\eta - \sigma(\eta)))$ = $CI(\prod_{\sigma ∈ S}(\eta - \sigma(\eta))) = CI$.
It suffices to prove that $D_{L/K}$ = $I$.

For each prime ideal $P$ of $A$, let $(D_{L/K})_P$ and $I_P$ be the localizations of
$D_{L/K}$ and $I$ with respect to the multiplicative subset $S = A - P$ respectively.
It suffices to prove that $(D_{L/K})_P$ = $I_P$ for each prime ideal $P$ of $A$.
Therefore, by replacing $A$ by $A_P$, we can assume that $A$ is a principal ideal domain.
Since  $B$ is finitely generated torsion-free A-module, $B$ is a free $A$-module.
Let $\omega_1,...,\omega_n$ be its basis over $A$.

Let $\xi$ = $\omega_1X_1 + ... + \omega_nX_n ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_n]$.
Let $F(Y)$ = $\prod_{\sigma ∈ T}(Y - \sigma(\xi)) ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_n][Y]$.
Let $F'(Y)$ be the formal derivative of $F(Y)$ with respect to $Y$.
Then $F'(\xi)$ = $\prod_{\sigma ∈ S}(\xi - \sigma(\xi)) ∈ B[X_1, ..., X_n]$.
$N_{L/K}(I)$ = $N_{L/K}(I(F'(\xi)))$ = $I(N_{L/K}(F'(\xi)))$ = $I(\prod_{\sigma ∈ T}F'(\sigma(\xi))))$ = $I(\Delta[1, \xi, ..., {\xi}^{n-1}]^2)$, where $\Delta[1, \xi, ..., {\xi}^{n-1}]$ is the Vandermonde determinant(for the relation between norms and forms, see section 14 of the Hilbert's book).

We have $\xi^{i}$ = $\omega_1{u_{i,1}}$ $+ ... +$ $\omega_n{u_{i,n}}$, $i$ = $0, 1, ..., n-1$,
where $u_{i,j} ∈ A[X_1, ..., X_n]$.
Hence $\Delta[1, \xi, ..., {\xi}^{n-1}]$ = $\Delta[\omega_1 ..., \omega_n]det(U)$,
where $\Delta[\omega_1 ..., \omega_n]$ is the determinant of a matrix $(\sigma(\omega_i))$ and $U$ is a matrix $(u_{i,j})$.
Hence $\Delta[1, \xi, ..., {\xi}^{n-1}]^2$ = $\Delta[\omega_1 ..., \omega_n]^2(det(U))^2$.

Let $d_{L/K}$ be the discriminant of $L/K$.
Since $(\Delta[\omega_1 ..., \omega_n]^2)A$ = $d_{L/K}$, $N_{L/K}(I)$ = $d_{L/K}I((det(U))^2)$.
Therefore $N_{L/K}(I) ⊂ d_{L/K}$.
We will show that $N_{L/K}(I)$ = $d_{L/K}$.

Let $\alpha$ be an element of $B$.
Let $f(X)$ = $\prod_{\sigma ∈ T}(X - \sigma(\alpha))$.
Let $f'(X)$ be the formal derivative of $f(X)$.
We denote $f'(α)$ by $\delta(α)$.
Since $f(X) ∈ B[X]$, $\delta(α) ∈ B$.
Since $\delta(α)$  = $\prod_{\sigma ∈ S}(\alpha - \sigma(\delta))$, $\delta(\alpha) ∈ I$.
It can be proved that $D_{L/K}$ is generated by the set $\{\delta(\alpha); \alpha ∈ B\}$.
For a proof of this fact, see, for example, Lang's "Algebraic number theory" which uses non-Archemedian completions or Hecke's "Lectures on the theory of algebraic numbers" which uses only ideals.
Hence $D_{L/K} ⊂ I$.
Therefore there exists an ideal $M$ of $B$ such that $D_{L/K}$ = $IM$.
Taking norms of the both sides, we get $N_{L/K}(D_{L/K})$ = $N_{L/K}(I)N_{L/K}(M)$.
It is well-known that $N_{L/K}(D_{L/K})$ = $d_{L/K}$.
Hence $d_{L/K} ⊂ N_{L/K}(I)$.
Hence $N_{L/K}(I)$ = $d_{L/K}$ as desired.
Then $N_{L/K}(M)$ = $A$ and $M$ = $B$.
Therefore we get $D_{L/K}$ = $I$.
**QED**

**EDIT**
The following condition should be added in the above proof.
For each maximal ideal $P$ of $A$, the residue field $A/P$ is perfect.

**EDIT**
I think I found a proof of the theorem using P-adic completions.
It is easy to see that the theorem holds if there exists $\alpha ∈ B$ such that $B$ = $A[\alpha]$.
Combining the [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147272/hatm-p-cong-prod-i-hatm-q-i) and the following proposition, we are done.

**Proposition**
Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring.
Let $K$ be its field of fractions.
Let $L$ be a finite separable extension.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
Suppose that $B$ is a discrete valuation ring.
Let $\bar{K}$ be the residue field of A.
Let $\bar{L}$ be the residue field of B.
Suppose that $\bar{L}$ is a separable extension of $\bar{K}$.
Then there exists $\alpha ∈ B$ such that $B$ = $A[\alpha]$.

The proof can be found in Serre's Local fields, Proposition 12 in page 57, or Lang's Algebraic number theory, Proposition 3 in page 59.

**EDIT**
In the above proof, we also need the following result.

Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, $P$ its maximal ideal.
Let $\hat{A_P}$ be the completion of $A$ with respect to $P$-adic topology.
Then $\hat{A_P}$ is faithfully flat over $A$.

The proof can be found in Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra, Chap. III $§$3, No.5, Prop. 9.

**EDIT**
The question remains. How can we get rid of the use of P-adic completions from the proof?

**EDIT**
I crossposted this question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97708/a-proof-of-a-theorem-on-the-different-in-algebraic-number-fields).

Comment: I'm probably just unfamiliar with field theory in general, but could you please give a reference or brief introduction to what $ D_{L/K} $ means?

Comment: @Rankeya No. It's not the discriminant of $L/K$. I wrote a link to the Wikipedia article on the different of $L/K$.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Hmm, my bad. I am deleting my comment.