# $\hat{M_P}$ $\cong$ $\prod_{i}\hat{M_{Q_i}}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I think I came up with the following result.
But I'm not 100% sure.
Is this correct?
If yes, how does one prove this?

**Theorem?**
Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, $K$ its field of fractions.
Let $L$ be a finite separable extension of $K$.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
Let P be the maximal ideal of A.
Let $Q_i$, $i$ = $1, ..., r$ be the maximal ideals of $B$ lying over $P$.
Let $M$ be a finitely generated torsion-free module over $B$.
Let $\hat{M_P}$ be the completion of $M$ with respect to $P$-adic topology.
Let $\hat{M_{Q_i}}$ be the completion of $M$ with respect to $(Q_i)$-adic topology.
Then $\hat{M_P}$ $\cong$ $\prod_{i}\hat{M_{Q_i}}$

**EDIT**
I need this to prove [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144135/a-proof-of-a-theorem-on-the-different-in-algebraic-number-fields).

Comment: As $M$ is free and finite over $B$, the proof is same as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137888.

Comment: @Qil Right! I forgot B is a principal ideal domain. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Your "theorem" holds for any noetherian local ring $A$ and any finitely generated $B$-module $M$. The proof is contained in your answer in the above question.

Comment: @Qil That's interesting. I guess I need some effort to prove it, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $n\ge 1$, $B/P^nB$ is Artinian with maximal ideals $Q_i/P^nB$, so the canonical map 
$$ B/P^nB \to \prod_{1\le i\le r} B_{Q_i}/P^nB_{Q_i}$$
is an isomorphism. Tensoring by $M$ over $B$ we get a canonical isomorphism
$$ M/P^n M\simeq \prod_{1\le i\le r} M_{Q_i}/P^nM_{Q_i}.$$
As $Q_i^NB_{Q_i}\subseteq PB_{Q_i}\subseteq Q_iB_{Q_i}$ for some $N\ge 1$, we get
$$ \widehat{M}=\varprojlim_n M/P^nM\simeq \prod_{1\le i\le r} \widehat{M_{Q_i}}.$$ 
In fact the theorem you cited is not used here (it is useful if we take inverse limit of the first isomorphism before tensoring by $M$).

Comment: Thanks. I need to digest your proof. Please wait for a while until I accept it.

Comment: So if $M$ is a torsion free $B$-module,then $B \otimes M \simeq M$ ?  How to show it ?