# A yet another theorem on the different ideal of algebraic number fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I think I came up with a proof of the following theorem using non-archimedian completions.
But I'm not 100% sure.
Is this correct?

**Theorem**
Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions.
Suppose that for each maximal ideal $P$ of $A$, the residue field $A/P$ is perfect.
Let $L$ be a finite separable extension of $K$.
Let $B$ be the integral closures of $A$ in $L$.
Let $\alpha$ be an element of $B$.
Let $f(X)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$.
Let $f'(X)$ be the formal derivative of $f(X)$.
We denote $f'(\alpha)$ by $\delta(\alpha)$.
Since $f(X) ∈ B[X]$, $\delta(\alpha) ∈ B$.
Let $D_{L/K}$ be the [different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal).
Then $D_{L/K}$ is generated by the set $\{\delta(\alpha); \alpha ∈ B\}$.

**Proof**
Let $I$ be the ideal generated by the set $\{\delta(\alpha); \alpha ∈ B\}$.
For each prime ideal $P$ of $A$, let $(D_{L/K})_P$ and $I_P$ be the localizations of
$D_{L/K}$ and $I$ with respect to the multiplicative subset $S = A - P$ respectively.
It suffices to prove that $(D_{L/K})_P$ = $I_P$ for each prime ideal $P$ of $A$.
Therefore, by replacing $A$ by $A_P$, we can assume that $A$ is a discrete valuation ring.
It is easy to see that the theorem holds if there exists $\alpha ∈ B$ such that $B$ = $A[\alpha]$.
Combining the [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147272/hatm-p-cong-prod-i-hatm-q-i) and the following propositions, I think we are done.

**Proposition 1**
Let $K$, $L$, $A$, $B$, $D_{L/K}$ be as in the theorem.
Let $I$ be the ideal generated by the set $\{\delta(\alpha); \alpha ∈ B\}$.
Then $I$ $⊂$ $D_{L/K}$.

**Proof**
Suppose that $\delta(\alpha)$ $≠$ 0.
Let $f(X)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$.
Let $g(X)$ = $f(X)/(X - \alpha)$ = $X^{n-1} $ $ + $ $ a_{n-2}X^{n-2} $ $ + ... + $ $ a_0$ $∈ B[X]$. Let $\mu ∈ (D_{L/K})^{-1}$. 
Let $h(X)$ = $Tr(\mu{f(X)}/(X - \alpha))$ = $Tr(\mu)X^{n-1}$ $ $ + $ $ $Tr(\mu{a_{n-2}})X^{n-2}$ $ $ + ... + $ $ $Tr(\mu{a_0})$.
Since $\mu ∈ (D_{L/K})^{-1}$, $h(X) ∈ B[X]$.
Replacing $X$ of $h(X)$ with $\alpha$, we get $\mu{f'(\alpha)}$ = $h(\alpha)$.
Hence $\mu{f'(\alpha)} ∈ B$.
Hence $f'(\alpha)$ $∈$ $D_{L/K}$.
Therefore $I$ $⊂$ $D_{L/K}$.

**Proposition 2**
Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring.
Let $K$ be its field of fractions.
Let $L$ be a finite separable extension.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
Suppose that $B$ is a discrete valuation ring.
Let $\bar{K}$ be the residue field of A.
Let $\bar{L}$ be the residue field of B.
Suppose that $\bar{L}$ is a separable extension of $\bar{K}$.
Then there exists $\alpha ∈ B$ such that $B$ = $A[\alpha]$.

The proof can be found in Serre's Local fields, Proposition 12 in page 57, or Lang's Algebraic number theory, Proposition 3 in page 59.

**Proposition 3**
Let $A$ be a complete discrete valuation ring.
Let $K$ be its field of fractions.
Let $L$ be a finite separable extension.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
Let $\bar{K}$ be the residue field of A.
Let $\bar{L}$ be the residue field of B.
Suppose that $\bar{L}$ is a separable extension of $\bar{K}$.
Then there exists $\alpha ∈ B$ such that $B$ = $A[\alpha]$.

The proof is immediate using proposition 2.

**Proposition 4**
Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, $P$ its maximal ideal.
Let $\hat{A_P}$ be the completion of $A$ with respect to $P$-adic topology.
Then $\hat{A_P}$ is faithfully flat over $A$.

The proof can be found in Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra, Chap. III $§$3, No.5, Prop. 9.

**Proposition 5**
Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions.
Let $L$ be a finite separable extension of $K$.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
Let P be the maximal ideal of A.
Let Q be a maximal ideals of $B$ lying over $P$.
Let $D_{L/K}$ be the different.
Let $\hat{L_Q}$, $\hat{B_Q}$, $\hat{K_P}$ be completions.
Let $(D_{L/K})_Q$ be the ideal of $\hat{B_Q}$ generated by $D_{L/K}$.
Then $(D_{L/K})_Q$ is the different of $\hat{L_Q}$ over $\hat{K_P}$

The proof can be found in Serre's Local fields, chapter 3, section 4, Proposition 10 in page 52.